# Code Igniter multiple form submissions issue

Tags: controller, codeigniter-3, csrf, postback, double-click

I can't figure out exactly what is causing my Code Igniter application to submit data twice, but I am really worried it is going to be a source of bugs and performance issues (x2 the database usage) later on.

My state changing webpage is `/user/login`

I suspect that it is CRSF.

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = TRUE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'xg93ScAg5VzEG';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'xgesheE7EfuBZ';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

This is my router, the page in question is user/login

```
$route['user/login'] = 'user/login';
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]     
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here is the page

```
  <FORM method="POST" action="user/login">

  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">

   <button type="submit" onClick="this.innerHTML='Processing...'; this.disabled=true; ">Login </button>

  </FORM>
```

After reading up on what can cause double page submissions, the list seems wildly eclectic, browser dependent, and not at all a stable list across time.

Question: What's the easiest and most re-usable way to stop my pages (assuming it's application wide) from calling my Controller method twice?

I want to stop the flow before it hits the database, out of database performance concerns.

Comment: Why do you suspect CSRF? Have you tried turning it off, i.e. `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` and does that stop the double submit?

Comment: The route - `$route['user/login'] = 'user/login';` - is not needed.

Comment: What is happening in the Console (Networking tab)? If there are multiple entries here it suggests the front end is responsible - if its only 1 then its a backend issue.